Overlay SwiftUI Color over UINavigation tabbar when using HostingController
I have a swiftUI view embed in UIhostingController with UInavigation. What I'm trying to achieve is that when I'm presenting a .sheet overlay I want to overlay remainder of the screen with black color with opacity.
something like this:
    public var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.color(for: ColorToken.Background._02, colorScheme: colorScheme)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        mainContent
            .padding(.top)
        if store.bottomSheetPosition != .hidden {
            Color.black
                .opacity(0.6)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .transition(.opacity)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    send(.didTapDismissBottomSheet, animation: .easeOut(duration: 0.3))
                }
        }
    }

Problem that I'm facing right now is that even tho it covers remainder screen with color, navigation buttons are still on the top of the view heirarchy, so they are not covered and are tappable.
it looks like this:

What are my options?
